# Using gulp.series to run two tasks sequentially isn't working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, gulp

First of all, I'm new on using Gulp.

I'm trying to create two tasks for CSS/SASS processing. First task needs to compile SASS into CSS (using `gulp-sass` and `node-sass`), and output the resulting files into `assets/dist/css` folder. This task is working like a charm.

The second task needs to use `gulp-purgecss` to traverse the resulting CSS files (from task 1) and remove unused CSS rules, outputting the clean CSS files into `assets/dist/css/min` folder. But, unfortunatelly, this task isn't working as expected.

I've created a "css" task that triggers, with `gulp.series`, my two tasks in the expected order, but looks like the second task - purgecss - is started before the files are finished by the first task - SASS compiling -, so the clean CSS files doesn't appear on `assets/dist/css/min` folder.

For testing, I've ran the "css" task twice, and, on the second time, the `assets/dist/css/min` folder appears containing my clean CSS, but those are based on old CSS files (generated on first run of "css" task), not the "fresh" ones generated on the second time.

Here is the tasks I mentioned:

```js
gulp.task("css:build", (done) => {
    gulp.src("./assets/src/scss/admin/admin.scss")
        .pipe(sass.sync({
            outputStyle: "compressed"
        }).on("error", sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./assets/dist/css"));
    
    gulp.src("./assets/src/scss/theme/theme.scss")
        .pipe(sass.sync({
            outputStyle: "compressed"
        }).on("error", sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./assets/dist/css"));

    done();
});

gulp.task("css:purge", (done) => {
    gulp.src("./assets/dist/css/theme.css")
        .pipe(purgecss({
            content: ['./**/*.php']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./assets/dist/css/min"));

    done();
});

gulp.task("css:watch", (done) => {
    gulp.watch("./assets/src/scss/**/*.scss", gulp.series("css:build", "css:purge"));
    
    done();
});

gulp.task("css", gulp.series("css:build", "css:purge"));
```

My guess is that `gulp.series` isn't working as expected, waiting the `css:build` to complete before starting `css:purge`.

Can someone help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After a few hours of search, I've reached the solution.

I only needed to remove the callback call `done()` from my tasks and added a `return` statement before the `gulp.src`. First of all, I used `done()` instead of `return` because, in the css:build task, I need to process two CSS files. But, now, I figured out that `gulp.src` accepts an array of strings instead only a string.

So, here's how my code looks now:

```js
gulp.task("css:build", () => {
    return gulp.src(["./assets/src/scss/admin/admin.scss", "./assets/src/scss/theme/theme.scss"])
        .pipe(sass.sync({
            outputStyle: "compressed"
        }).on("error", sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./assets/dist/css"));
});

gulp.task("css:purge", () => {
    return gulp.src("./assets/dist/css/*.css")
        .pipe(purgecss({
            content: [
                "./*.php",
                "./templates/**/*.php"
            ]
        }))
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: ".min"
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./assets/dist/css"));
});

gulp.task("css:watch", () => {
    return gulp.watch("./assets/src/scss/**/*.scss", gulp.series("css:build", "css:purge"));
});

gulp.task("css", gulp.series("css:build", "css:purge"));
```

The trick is: Gulp tasks are asynchronous, so the css:purge task was finishing before css:build, and, because it's asynchronous, the `done()` was fired before the tasks was really ended. So, returning the task itself (`return gulp.src()`) is like returning a promise, and `gulp.series` now waits for this promise to be completed before starting the next task.